# Which hook do I use to edit pending comment count on wordpress dashboard?

Tags: comments

[image]

The picture gives an illustration of the pending comments I am referring to. As you can see, the number shown on the menu bar is different from the number shown on the pending column.

I am trying to find a way to edit the numbers highlighted in yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually adjust this number using the following method.

```php
function adjust_wp_comments_count( $original_counts ) {
    $counts = new \stdClass();
    $counts->moderated = 99;
    return $counts;
}
add_filter( 'wp_count_comments', 'adjust_wp_comments_count', 100, 1 );
```

The line: `$counts->moderated = 99` is what you will need to adjust if you want to set it to a particular value or calculation of your choosing.

Note: I've set the filter priority to 100 as I found other plugins also affect this. It depends on your setup. If you add this filter and it doesn't work, change `100` to `100000` or any other large number. The higher the number, the more likely that your modifications will take effect.

WordPress also dynamically changes the comment counts on-the-fly as you change comment status in the Edit Comments page. This code **doesn't take any of that into consideration**. It simply provides you a mechanism to set the number as it's displayed when the page loads.

Note: Forcefully setting this value may have unintended consequences elsewhere in the system. Test and evaluate for your particular circumstances.

Comment: I'd recommend passing the filter's parameters so you don't lose the existing comment counts. See [the filter's documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_count_comments/).

Comment: Yea, makes sense if they need it. Updated the code, cheers.